# Receive Push Messages in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, push-notification

To receive Push messages in iOS I am using the following method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

This method is in my AppDelegate.m. Everything works good. My question is if it is possible that this method is not in AppDelegate but anywhere else?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible since this is determined by iOS. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html).

What you can do is create a dedicated class (e.g. `PushNotificationHandler`) that should be there to handle your push notifications and invoke it within `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`.

Comment: yeah sorry for the bad news :/

Answer (score 0):

With NSNotificationCenter you can easily broadcast your push notification:

Broadcast:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"localNotification": notification};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DOMyApplicationDidReceiveLocalNotification"
                                                        object:notification 
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Listen where needed:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"DOMyApplicationDidReceiveLocalNotification"
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = note.userInfo[@"localNotification"];

   //... 
}];
```

NSNotificationCenter offers a variety of method for listening, not only the block-based shown here.